# GAE Python WebApp2 url/resource/:id/resource

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to write a API that has a "boat" resource and I want to build off of that url with an ID and another resource.

```
localhost:8080/boat/absk12712480/arrival
```

I originally had:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ...
    ('/boat/(.*)/arrival', ArrivalHandler),
    ...
    ], debug=True)
```

But that kept grabbing the "/arrival" as part of the ID. So I tried:

```
('/boat/(.*?(?=\/)/arrival', ArrivalHandler)
('/boat/(.*?(?=\/arrival)/arrival', ArrivalHandler)
```

Is what I am trying to do possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `('/boat/(.*)/arrival', ArrivalHandler)` the regex is too greedy, and doesn't match the [webapp2 URI format](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#the-url-template).  If the ID is always just lower-case ascii and digits, you could use:

`('/boat/<:[a-z0-9]+>/arrival', ArrivalHandler)`

ought to work, or

`('/boat/<id:[a-z0-9]+>/arrival', ArrivalHandler)`

if you want a named parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your help. With your regex help I found the solution. **('/boat/([A-z0-9\-]+)/arrival'** I needed the () because I am using the Lazy Handler